# How can I update a value in Parse when using two PFUser Object to query objects?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm a newbie in iOS and Parse. Right now I'm trying to create a social network app in iOS with Parse. In my app, I'm creating a friend system which allows users to create connection with others.

Assuming that there is a user sent an request to current user, and the request was successfully received. To confirm the request, I query the class with two PFUser objects which are **current user `[PFUser currentUser]`** and **the user who sent the request `(PFUser *user1)`**. Then, I update the status from **Request** to **Confirm** so that I can create connection between these two users.

Here is the code:

```
PFQuery *connectActivity = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:FriendClass];
[connectActivity whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:user1];
[connectActivity whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[connectActivity whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Request"];
[connectActivity getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if (!error) {
             [object setObject:@"status" forKey:@"Confirm"];
             [object saveInBackground];
      }
}];
```

However, when I run the code, it shows me the error that `Cannot set fromUser on FriendClass to a user other than current user. (Code:141)`, and it does not have any result. I don't have a clue of this error.

Does someone know why it happens and how to make it work? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that you have a beforeSave trigger for FriendClass which checks to see if fromUser == request.user, and spits back that error if not.  You could wrap that in an if statement that checks `object.dirty("fromUser")`

Comment: Note - I mean to put this check inside the beforeSave trigger on your cloud code, not on your iOS client coce.

Comment: I added an if statement that checks `toUser === currentUser`, then it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Careful - you might be making editing things from your dashboard fail, since those don't have a `request.user`.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem ;)